# MySQL List LIKE (similar) except one

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make similar listing table at the end of the my product page.
For example - Molernmerk 383S
My variable to get similar ones is first 3-letter the product.

Yes it is working but the same product name is in it. I dont want to list same product name in similar one's list. (except "Molernmerk 383S" - this function i think the solution but i didnt use it...)

Here is my code,

```
$pname = substr($productname, 0, 3);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigdata WHERE product_names LIKE '$pname%' limit 10");
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*`API. It is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*`or pdo with prepared statements.

Comment: then just explicitly add an and clause in your query to exclude it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be

```
    $pname = substr($productname, 0, 3);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigdata WHERE
     id != $productId AND
     product_names LIKE '$pname%' limit 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ID of the omitted product immediately available in that script?  If so, you can do

```
$pname = substr($productname, 0, 3);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigdata WHERE
     id != $productId AND
     product_names LIKE '$pname%' limit 10");
```

Otherwise, you can query the databases with `$productname` and find the ID for the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pname = substr($productname, 0, 3);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigdata WHERE product_names LIKE '$pname%' AND product_names != '$productname' GROUP BY product_names limit 10");
```